Using GeoPackage view in QField
I need to have two views in a QField data entry project to facilitate the symbolization of two tables.
There is a point parent table with a 1:many relationship to a non-spatial child table using a UUID field as a primary/foreign key. The first view is of the point parent table and its purpose is to standardize the two types of azimuth measurements collected into a single azimuth method which will allow rotation of the symbols. The second view joints the child table to the parent table creating a point layer with a calculated azimuth for rotation of the symbolization of the child records.
So the data will be collected in the two tables while the two views are used to symbolize the data on the map. The tables & views are in geopackage and all work well in QGIS.
But when I “Package Project for QField”, the views won’t work properly.  If I export the views with the Action of “Copy” they are exported to a separate GeoPackage and do not reference the copy of the two tables that I am collecting data on. If I export the views with the Action of “Offline editing” the views are exported as tables within the GeoPackage.
How do I use views of tables to help symbolize the data that I am actively collecting in QField? Is this even possible in QField?

I use virtual layers in my QField set up and this works well. You should be able to mimic your view with a virtual layer.
